# Help required with timeval structure in C

Tags: c, struct

I needed to calculate the time it takes to run a certain function and ran into the following code (source: http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/4254 ) with the claim that "...record & output the execution time of a piece of code in microseconds"

```
/* Put this line at the top of the file: */
#include <sys/time.h>

/* Put this right before the code you want to time: */
struct timeval timer_start, timer_end;
gettimeofday(&timer_start, NULL);

/* Put this right after the code you want to time: */
gettimeofday(&timer_end, NULL);
double timer_spent = timer_end.tv_sec - timer_start.tv_sec + (timer_end.tv_usec - timer_start.tv_usec) / 1000000.0;
printf("Time spent: %.6f\n", timer_spent);
```

but my personal experience with the piece of code shows that the output 'time' is in seconds instead of microseconds. I need some input on whether I am right or wrong (I need to clarify this once and for all).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right.

The `tv_sec` member of the structure stores seconds, and the `tv_usec` member (microseconds) is converted to seconds by dividing by 10^6.

Answer (score 1):

It provides the time difference in seconds **and** microseconds (with the following term: `(timer_end.tv_usec - timer_start.tv_usec)`). So you should be ok :)

Comment: Yes I guess you are right. Seems like I misconceived the question.

Answer (score -1):

Modify like this:

```
double timer_spent = (timer_end.tv_sec - timer_start.tv_sec)*1e6 + (timer_end.tv_usec - timer_start.tv_usec);
```

Comment: No, you would also have to multiply the first part by 10^6 to convert seconds to microseconds.