# declare struct timeval time inside a function

Tags: c, random, time, struct

I have done some search about problems when [using time.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21520206/timeval-struct-usage) to obtain a [random](http://habibidavid.blogspot.com/2012/03/gaussian-distribution-random-numbers.html) seed [initialization](http://forums.devshed.com/unix-help-35/pthread_create-question-196261.html). Particularly in my case, I want to place the [time](http://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime) outside the main function.

Based on the comments I made some changes. After including twice in the include as  and , these errors and warning went off:

```
too few arguments to function ‘random’
implicit declaration of function ‘srandom’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
too few arguments to function ‘random’
```

Once I declared the code as:

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <math.h>
int main(void)
{
    struct timeval time;
    ...
}
```

It works, however it has to move outside main. But if I change to:

```
#include <sys/time.h>
struct timeval time;
int main(void)
{
    ...
}
```

It gives me the error:

```
‘time’ redeclared as different kind of symbol
```

In my case the implementation I am working on is in C not in [C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12776022/why-am-i-getting-this-redeclared-as-different-kind-of-symbol-error). When I try to move the code to a function in order to receive a different random number every time my function is called, some other errors happen:

```
double myRandom(double dAverage,double dStddev);

double myRandom(double dAverage,double dStddev){
    int iRandom1, iRandom2;
    double dRandom1, dRandom2,result;
    long int liSampleSize;

    iRandom1=(random());
    dRandom1=(double)iRandom1 /2147483647;
    iRandom2=(random());
    dRandom2=(double)iRandom2 /2147483647;
    result= dAverage + dStddev * sqrt(-2.0 * log(dRandom1))*cos(6.28318531 * dRandom2);

    return(result);
}

int main(void){
    ...
    struct timeval time;
    gettimeofday(&time, NULL);
    srandom((unsigned int) time.tv_usec);

    for (i=0; i<liSampleSize;i++)
    {   result=myRandom(dAverage,dStddev);
    }
}
```

Apparently it [should be working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6536407/help-required-with-timeval-structure-in-c). Has somebody any idea what is wrong here. All comments are highly appreciated.

Update: Then, taking srandom out of myRandom makes the generated values as expected. So, it worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first error is related to `time.h`. Including it introduces some instance called `time` to your global namespace.

The second is most likely because you haven't included `stdlib.h`.

Comment: I changed the time adding it in both ways. that's odd, but worked.